# How To Structure Extensions Within An AMD TypeScript Program

Tags: typescript, amd

I am writing a program in TypeScript that mainly follows an AMD loading pattern whereby classes are loaded using an import statement.

```
import TestRunner = require('../TS/TestRunner');
```

I do, however, want to include some extension methods that extend objects such as `NodeList` - so there will be a small number of extension files that contain an extension to the `lib.d.ts` interfaces and then an implementation of the additional feature - for example...

```
interface NodeList {
    extensionMethod(...info): NodeList;
}

NodeList.prototype.extensionMethod = function (...info: string[]) {
    return this;
};
```

I *could* just include all the extensions at the start of my program so they are available - but I would actually like to load them on demand just like the rest of the code. The problem is, the file containing the extensions doesn't really export anything to use - it just adds this code to existing objects.

What is the best way to include the extensions in my TypeScript program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a setup that works. Key points:

- You'll need to place the `interface` extensions in a file that is *not* an external module (otherwise you'll be declaring a new interface in the external module scope rather than extending the existing type).
- This only works on objects defined at the global scope. Extending other objects' prototypes is dangerous enough already, so no big loss on that account.
- You'll need to manually invoke `require`. For AMD scenarios, use the undocumented `/// <amd-depdendency path="path" />` tag.
- The file containing the extensions can be an external module if needed.

**myExtensions.d.ts**

```
// In case you're not using node.d.ts
declare var process: process;

interface process {
    getFour: any;
}
```

**extensions.ts**

```
/// <reference path="myExtensions.d.ts" />

process.getFour = () => 4;
```

**consumer.ts**

```
/// <reference path="myExtensions.d.ts" />

// In case you're not using node.d.ts
declare var require;

// Manual import of extensions
require('./extensions');

console.log(process.getFour()); // Works
```